# Anova on Normalised Data

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, normalization

I have cells expressing a protein under three conditions; Control and two different treatments. I have repeated this experiment 9 times. I need to see whether the treatments are affecting the level of protein but due to biological and microscope variability, data from each of the 9 repeats are of different orders of magnitude.

To test whether there is a difference, I have been given two pieces of advice; normalize the data by dividing by control for each repeat and then use anova with one column of 1's for the control OR use repeated measures ANOVA and treat the scores from within each session as paired to account for trending. Can anyone tell me which is best and cite proof?

Comment: What have you exactly measured on those 9 occasions for each of the three groups?

Comment: To explain a little more, I have derived brain cells from stem cells, treated them and then tagged them with a fluorescent stain. I then measure the average  florescence of the cells on a microscope and get units of florescence for each treatment group. I have done this whole process 9 times and so have 9 sets of 3 data points.